# Android: Authentication is requied. You need to sign into your Google account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm doing a program for the sale of books. Last week I tested purchase (InApp) and everything worked (immediately on release version). Yesterday trying to buy a book, I get a message: Authentication is requied. You need to sign into your Google account (screen - http://itmages.ru/image/view/1997152/c352d7e3). This message on all devices. How to fix it?

Comment: can you please double check if you are logged in into your Google account on your phone? Can you access/download apps on GOogle Play Store?

Comment: I deleted the app on phone and installed it again from Google Play. The error appears again.

Comment: Can you try with different google account on your phone and see if it works? You can't purchase item with same google account which you have used in google play store.

Comment: I corrected the mistake. It was necessary first to lay out the alpha version of the application and test purchases. Then raise the status on the release.

Comment: What do you mean "raise the status on the release" ?